# How to use ternary Operator in my C/C++ code

Tags: c++, c, c++11, c++14, conditional-operator

I have 3 values. Can you guide me on how can I use the ternary operator instead of if-else if statement in the mentioned example?

```
if(status == ok)
{
  return;
}
else
{
 if(status == warning)
 {
   return E_ABORT;
 } 
 else if(status == stop)
 { 
   return E_FAIL;
 }
```

In 2 cases (stop and warning) i want message and in ok case just want return, no message want to
display

Comment: Why ternary? `switch-case` maybe?

Comment: What is `status`?

Comment: *Why* ? The code you have is expressive, functional, debugger-friendly, and crystal-clear in intent. why on earth would you bork that up with a chain of ternary expressions? "Because I can" isn't a reason in itself.

Comment: The ternary operator should return a value. Your code doesn't do that. It is not intended for running conditional code blocks.

Comment: yes i know, still i want to do same code with ternary operator as one of my friends asked me.
I tried to use ternary but totally pissed off now. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: You can't mix `return;` and `return ...;` in the same function. The latter implies the function has a non-`void` return type, so `return;` would be either *undefined behavior* or a compile error.

Comment: When you have a `return` in the positive `if` branch, you can omit the `else` since any code that can bypass the `if` must have failed the conditional expression.


This helps reduce indentation in the rest of the function.  As soon as a function is able to return it should.  This avoids storing state longer than needed.

Answer (score 3):

The ternary operator is used to evaluate an expression or one or more values based on a condition.

Your code isn't just evaluating expressions but running different statements in each case.  As such, using the ternary operator is not appropriate for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You need **two** ternary operators:

```
return status == ok ? SOMETHING_YOU_DIDNT_SHOW_US
    : status == warning ? E_ABORT
    : E_FAIL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator is not suitable in your case. Use switch if you want an alternative to if-else.

```
switch(status) {
    case "ok": return;
    case "warning": cout<<"My status is Warn, Can proceed!";
                    break;
    case "stop": cout<<"My status is Stop, Can't proceed!";
                 break;
}
```

If you want to use ternary operator anyway, then you can use this way.

```
string result = (status == "ok") ? "" : (status == "warning") ? "My status is Warn, Can proceed!" : "My status is Stop, Can't proceed!";
cout<<result;
```

Comment: Note that this use of ternary will result in an empty string being sent to `cout` which does not happen in the original code.

Comment: I was just trying to give him/her an idea how to use ternary operator in this case. Obviously its a no no to use ternary operator here.